# C++: Create dynamic database using sqlite for transferring voice stream

Tags: c++, database, sqlite, soap

I am having list of char array by that I want to store all  items in SQLite database , my  question how to store  string array values in an SQLite database where my string array is dynamically changeable because string array values are coming from server.

here i am done sqlite3 Insert item through Passing parameter , I want to just use this database in dynamically.. Can any guys give me any idea.
    I am new to C++ development:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "sqlite3.h"
#include<string.h>
#define STRING_MAX 32

typedef struct metadata_t {
    char userid[256];
    char firstname[256];
    char lastname[256];
    char username[256];
    char password[256];
    char email[256];
    char userphone[256];
    char time[256];
} metadata_t;

void insertdata1(metadata_t * data);

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{

    struct metadata_t *data;
    cin >> data->userid;
    cin >> data->firstname;
    cin >> data->lastname;
    cin >> data->username;
    cin >> data->password;
    cin >> data->email;
    cin >> data->userphone;
    cin >> data->time;

    insertdata1(data);

}

void insertdata1(metadata_t * data)
{
    sqlite3 *db;
    sqlite3_open("test1.db", &db);

    string createQuery =
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS items (userid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, firstname TEXT,lastname TEXT,username TEXT,password TEXT,email text,userphone INTEGER, "
        "time TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT (NOW()));";
    sqlite3_stmt *createStmt;
    cout << "Creating Table Statement" << endl;
    sqlite3_prepare(db, createQuery.c_str(), createQuery.size(),
            &createStmt, NULL);
    cout << "Stepping Table Statement" << endl;
    if (sqlite3_step(createStmt) != SQLITE_DONE)
        cout << "Didn't Create Table!" << endl;

    char *a = "(";
    char *d = ")";
    char *b = "'";
    char *c = ",";
    char str1[1000];
    char *str2 = "";
    char *g = ";";
    strcpy(str1,
           "INSERT INTO items (userid,firstname,lastname,username,password,email,userphone,time)VALUES");

    strcat(str1, a);

    strcat(str1, b);
    strcat(str1, data->userid);
    strcat(str1, b);
    strcat(str1, c);
    strcat(str1, b);
    strcat(str1, data->firstname);
    strcat(str1, b);
    strcat(str1, c);
    strcat(str1, b);
    strcat(str1, data->lastname);
    strcat(str1, b);
    strcat(str1, c);
    strcat(str1, b);
    strcat(str1, data->username);
    strcat(str1, b);
    strcat(str1, c);
    strcat(str1, b);
    strcat(str1, data->password);
    strcat(str1, b);
    strcat(str1, c);
    strcat(str1, b);
    strcat(str1, data->email);
    strcat(str1, b);
    strcat(str1, c);
    strcat(str1, b);
    strcat(str1, data->userphone);
    strcat(str1, b);
    strcat(str1, c);
    strcat(str1, b);
    strcat(str1, data->time);
    strcat(str1, b);
    strcat(str1, d);
    strcat(str1, g);

    std::string insertQuery = str1; // WORKS!
    sqlite3_stmt *insertStmt;
    cout << "Creating Insert Statement" << endl;
    sqlite3_prepare(db, insertQuery.c_str(), insertQuery.size(),
            &insertStmt, NULL);
    cout << "Stepping Insert Statement" << endl;
    if (sqlite3_step(insertStmt) != SQLITE_DONE)
        cout << "Didn't Insert Item!" << endl;

}
```

Comment: Are you looking for an alternative implementation? Your `strcat` operations can be replaced by `std::string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO items (userid,firstname,lastname,username,password,email,userphone,time)VALUES(";
insertQuery = insertQuery   + "'" + data->userid    + "'," + "'" + data->firstname + "'," + "'" + data->lastname  + "'," + "'" + data->username  + "'," + "'" + data->password  + "'," + "'" + data->email     + "'," + "'" + data->userphone + "'," + "'" + data->time      + "');";`. Cant you use `std::string` instead of `char [256]`?

Comment: Also, in C++ `typedef` for `struct` is redundant. `*data` is a pointer to the structure & should be allocated memory or better yet, make it a variable on stack. Consider using `<cstring>` instead of `<string.h>` although you can altogether avoid it

Comment: sqlite suggestion: Make use of `sqlite3_errmsg` or function from that family of functions for a more meaningful error message. Also you could make use of `stderr` for errors instead of `stdout`. You can also add check for return value of `sqlite3_open`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use [bind variables](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) - they make your code cleaner and more protected against input errors and even SQL injections.

There are also good habits that won't hurt:

- check return value after every call to `sqlite3_*` functions and write output of `sqlite3_errmsg()` to `stderr` (=`cerr`) or to a log file in case of error;
- cleanup after we're done by calling `sqlite3_finalize()` on every prepared statement when it's no longer used.

Not following these practices will make your karma suffer when someone else uses or debugs your code later.

So, here is the suggested `insertdata1()` (I hope, it's more clean and readable now):

```cpp
// some basic error handling
void exit_with_sqlite_error(sqlite3 *db, const char* file, int line)
{
cerr << "Error: " << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << " at " << file << ":" << line << endl;
exit(1);
}

// helps to get exact location of an error 
#define EXIT_WITH_SQLITE_ERR(db) \
exit_with_sqlite_error(db, __FILE__, __LINE__)

void insertdata1(metadata_t *data)
{
sqlite3 *db;
sqlite3_open("test1.db", &db);

string createQuery = 
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS items ("
    "userid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,'
    "firstname TEXT,"
    "lastname TEXT,"
    "username TEXT,"
    "password TEXT,'
    "email TEXT,"
    "userphone INTEGER,"
    "time TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT (NOW()));";

cout << "Creating Table Statement" << endl;
int rc = sqlite3_exec(db, createQuery.c_str(), NULL, NULL, NULL);
if (rc != SQLITE_OK) 
    EXIT_WITH_SQLITE_ERR(db);

sqlite3_stmt *insertStmt = NULL;
rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, 
    "INSERT INTO items "
    "(userid,firstname,lastname,username,password,email,userphone,time)"
    "VALUES"
    "(:userid,:firstname,:lastname,:username,:password,:email,:userphone,:time);",
    -1, &insertStmt, NULL);
if (rc != SQLITE_OK) EXIT_WITH_SQLITE_ERR(db);

rc = sqlite3_bind_int(insertStmt, 1, atoi(data->userid));
if (rc != SQLITE_OK) EXIT_WITH_SQLITE_ERR(db);
rc = sqlite3_bind_text(insertStmt, 2, data->firstname, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
if (rc != SQLITE_OK) EXIT_WITH_SQLITE_ERR(db);
rc = sqlite3_bind_text(insertStmt, 3, data->lastname, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
if (rc != SQLITE_OK) EXIT_WITH_SQLITE_ERR(db);
rc = sqlite3_bind_text(insertStmt, 4, data->username, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
if (rc != SQLITE_OK) EXIT_WITH_SQLITE_ERR(db);
rc = sqlite3_bind_text(insertStmt, 5, data->password, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
if (rc != SQLITE_OK) EXIT_WITH_SQLITE_ERR(db);
rc = sqlite3_bind_text(insertStmt, 6, data->email, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
if (rc != SQLITE_OK) EXIT_WITH_SQLITE_ERR(db);
rc = sqlite3_bind_int(insertStmt, 7, atoi(data->userphone));
if (rc != SQLITE_OK) EXIT_WITH_SQLITE_ERR(db);
rc = sqlite3_bind_text(insertStmt, 8, data->time, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
if (rc != SQLITE_OK) EXIT_WITH_SQLITE_ERR(db);

rc = sqlite3_step(insertStmt);
if (rc != SQLITE_DONE && rc != SQLITE_OK) EXIT_WITH_SQLITE_ERR(db);

sqlite3_finalize(insertStmt);

// call to sqlite3_close() helps to find resource leaks, because it fails
// if you have obvious leaks, such as prepared statements not finalized
rc = sqlite3_close(db);
if (rc != SQLITE_OK) EXIT_WITH_SQLITE_ERR(db);
}
```